# php glob and scandir function is not working on web server

Tags: php, mysql

i am using this glob function on my website dont know what is the problem.wasted too much time on this.its working on localhost but not working in webserver. please help me

code :

```
 $result = mysql_query($qry) or die ("Query failed");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    $HTML='';
    if($count > 0){
    while ($friendList = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {

     $_SESSION['PropertyId'] = $friendList['property_Id'];
     $Username = $friendList['UserName'];
     $qry1 = "SELECT Mobile_Number1,FirstName FROM registration WHERE UserName = '".$Username."'";
    $result1 = mysql_query($qry1) or die ("Query failed");
    $friendList1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
    $mobNo = $friendList1['Mobile_Number1'];
    $Name = $friendList1['FirstName']; 
    $image = "";
    $dir = "propertyImages/".$friendList['property_Id']."";
    $files = array();
    $files = glob("$dir/*.*");
    $image = "";
    print_r($files);
    if (count($files) > 0) 
    {
    $image = $files[0];
    }
    else
    {
    $image = 'img/1.jpg';
    }
```

Comment: i want only first image from that directory.but in array it does not displaying anything on server

Comment: are you sure `$friendList['property_Id']` is set, also put this at the begin of your script to see the error if has any `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Comment: $friendList['property_Id'] is coming from database.and it returning proper value

Comment: What do you mean by "It's working...and...not working"?

Comment: @NabilKadimi its working on localhost but not working in web server

Comment: Does the print_r display an empty array?

Comment: yes its display empty array

Comment: your folder isn't empty and the script doesnt show any error with the error_reporting? what system have your server?

Comment: @EmilioGort its not showing any error in firebug also

Comment: are you using ajax?, firebug is for client side...

Comment: yes i am using ajax that data is coming dyanamically without refresh the page..but i checked without ajax also

Comment: the error reporting doesnt show nothing??if you dont have set an error reporting you cant see any error

Comment: how to set error reporting

Comment: you have two options in php.ini or write this `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', true);` at top of your script

Comment: @EmilioGort and where i can see those error i have added this on my php page

Comment: try executing the php script whitout ajax

Comment: @EmilioGort i tried this without ajax but no success :(

Comment: I dont know my friend what could be the issue, the php's manual say: `Note: On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty match and an error.` try http://us1.php.net/readdir instead to get the work done, and read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

As @Emilio stated, try `readdir()` instead of `glob()`, especially because you are not really needing the pattern recognition glob() does provide.

Could you give this a try?

```
// enable error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// initialise empty $files array
$files= array();

if (file_exists($dir)) {
  $dh= opendir($dir);
  if ($dh) {
    while ($file= readdir($dh)) {

      // skip "." and ".."
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        echo "$file\n";
        $files[]= $file;
      }
    }
    closedir($dh);
  } else {
    print 'Directory handle could not be opened.';
  }
} else {
  print 'Directory not accessible or does not exist.';
}
```

General comments:

1.) another +1 for @Emilio's comment about mysql_* functions

2.) If you are running your script on a shared host you may also experience problems due to `safe_mode` being enabled.

3.) Checking for errors when using ajax calls: Firebug's Network panel will reveal the response returned from the server, just have it open while doing the call. If any error is output by the server you will see the error on the Response tab of the corresponding AJAX call.

4.) Regarding code: you don't need to initialise variables like $image or $files if they are directly overwritten, the two double quotes at the end of the `$dir = ...` are also obsolete. I would also recommend to decide for one variable style, best would be CamelCase syntax with a lowercase letter after the $.

Comment: i tried this code it prints "Directory not accessible or does not exist" but i have files in that folder

Comment: Files that you see using FTP which does not necessarily mean the owner of the PHP process does see. Tell us a bit about your production server, are you hosting it or is it on a shared host? If you are logged in via FTP, try to set the directory permissions on that folder to 0755 to make it readable by everyone.

Comment: Another idea to check path issues: if the directory containing the images is accessible for web users, upload a file containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to the directory and browse to that file, check the location returned in `SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` if it matches the directory you try to open in your script. If they are identical it has to be access permissions.